# Show that a $2$nd ordered, $1$-D equation $z_n=F(z_{n-1},z_{n-2})$ is equivalent to a set of two discrete equation of 1st order.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Show that a second-ordered, one-dimensional equation $z_n=F(z_{n-1},z_{n-2})$ is equivalent to a set of two discrete equations, where a discrete equation is of first order is of the form $x_n=F(x_{n-1})$. I really didn't understand my lecturer's notes regarding this "$F$" and didn't find alternative notes in the subject, since I am not native and the literature is not in English and it would take time until I study the equivalent terms in English. I could really use some guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if you let $\zeta_n:=z_{n-1}$, you got:
$$\left\{ \begin{split} \zeta_n &= z_{n-1} \\ z_n &= F(z_{n-1}, \zeta_{n-1})\; .\end{split}\right.$$
which is a system of recurrence equations of the first order.

Moreover, if you let $\mathbf{x}_n := (\zeta_n,z_n)$ and $\mathbf{F}(\mathbf{x}) := (z_n, F(z_n,\zeta_n))$, you can rewrite the previous system as a vectorial recurrence equation of the first order:
$$\mathbf{x}_n = \mathbf{F}(\mathbf{x}_{n-1})\; .$$

---

Just to give an example, let us consider the Fibonacci recurrence equation:
$$\tag{1} z_n = z_{n-1} + z_{n-2}\; .$$
It can be put in the form $z_n=F(z_{n-1},z_{n-2})$ by simply defining the function $F$ in the LHside as follows:
$$\begin{split} F: \mathbb{R}^2 &\to \mathbb{R} \\ (z,\zeta) &\mapsto z+\zeta\; .\end{split}$$
Therefore, the system of first order recurrence equations which is equivalent to (1) is:
$$\left\{ \begin{split} \zeta_n &= z_{n-1} \\ z_n &= F(z_{n-1}, \zeta_{n-1})\end{split}\right.\qquad \text{i.e.}\qquad \left\{ \begin{split} \zeta_n &= z_{n-1} \\ z_n &= z_{n-1} + \zeta_{n-1}\; .\end{split}\right.$$
On the other hand, if you let:
$$\begin{split} \mathbf{F}: \mathbb{R}^2 &\to \mathbb{R}^2\\ (\zeta, z) &\mapsto (z,z+\zeta)\end{split}$$
you can write the first order vectorial recurrence equation equivalent to (1), that is:
$$\mathbf{x}_n = \mathbf{F}(\mathbf{x}_{n-1})\qquad \text{i.e.}\qquad (\zeta_n, z_n) = (z_{n-1}, z_{n-1} + \zeta_{n-1})\; .$$

Comment: I thought of something like that, but I have a fundamental problem understanding what $F$ really is in practice.

Comment: Is the second equation actually discrete?

Comment: I will add an example to make things clearer. ;-)